# パラメータをGUIで変更したらそのパラメータに応じたグラフが描かれるようなツールが知りたい。

Tags: c

パラメータを変えたときのグラフの変化を眺めるためにタイトルに書いたように、パラメータをGUIで変更してそれに応じたグラフを描きたいです。
それを行うのに必要な知識・ツールと、それを学ぶための参考文献などがあれば教えてください。
現状C言語しか使えないのでC言語でできることだと嬉しいです。

なお、Windowsで使用することを想定しています。

Comment: 対象 OS は何でしょうか？ Windows / Linux / Android ? 　でもまあ今の状況だと「何もかも教える」ことになって、こういうサイトで扱うには範囲が広すぎるクローズになりそうです。　ですが、その程度のことなら Excel でなんとかなりそうな気がしますけどいかが？

Comment: パラメータ1つごとに1つの実験結果がCSVファイルに保存してあって、パラメータをGUIで（バーか何かで）変更すると変更後のパラメータでの実験結果が保存されてるCSVファイルからデータを読み込んでグラフとして表示させるということをしたいんですがエクセルで可能ですか？

Comment: 「自分でツール(プログラム)を作るのが目的」なのか、「データを与えてグラフを表示したいだけ(既存のツールでもOK)」なのかによって回答が変わってくると思います。

Comment: エクセルで可能ですか？という問いに対してはYesです。もしそのツールを今後もそれなりの期間、細かく変更（改善？）し続ける可能性があり、どんな変更が必要になるか不確定なのであれば、たとえ今はC言語だけしか知らなくとも、VBAを勉強してExcel上で実現するのが最も早そうです。およそのことには対応できると思います。逆に、単に表示さえできてしまえば、今後使うことも変更が必要になることもないのであれば、相応のツールを探した方が早いかもしれません。

Comment: カスタマイズする予定はないので表示できる既存のツールがあれば現状は十分です。

Comment: カスタマイズ予定があるのであればVBAをやるといいのですね。

Answer (score 0):

windowsだと想定して回答します。
C言語でGUI、グラフを作成できるツールはあるかどうか知りませんが、
言語がC#、C++であればツールがあります。
C#であればマイクロソフトのvisual studioがいいと思います。
C++であればエンバカデロのC++Builderというものがあります。
どちらも無料版がありますので、調べてみてください。
C#もC++も言語的にはC言語をベースにクラスを追加したようなものですので、
クラスの勉強をすれば使えるようになると思います。
また、C++よりC#の方が、覚えるのは楽だと思います。